# count of good permutations using dynamic programming

Tags: permutations, dynamic-programming

You are given a sequence of n numbers. Each number is either distinct or occurs in duplicate, i.e., each number in the sequence occurs at most two times. The goal is to count the number of permutations that are “good”. A good permutation is one in which no two duplicates occur together. For example if the sequence is 2 1 1 2, the number of good permutations are 2 which are: 1 2 1 2 and 2 1 2 1. (Note that any other permutation such as 1 2 2 1 is not good, since 2 and 2 occur next to each other.) If the sequence is 3 3, then there are no good permutations, and if the sequence is 2, then there is only one good permutation
{3,1,2,1,2,3} output : 30
{2,1,1} output : 1
e.g 1 1 2 -Bad
1 2 1 Good
1 2 1 Good(unique) pick only 1
etc
Hint: you only need the number of unique elements and the number of repeated elements in your dp. an element can only be repeated at most twice

Comments: Thanks for the contributions,so on what i have tried, I have tried solving this problem by simply n! * (n-1)! * 2!, that works when the repeated character is just one, then n! - "invalid"(n-1)!* duplicates * 2! + overlap * duplicates * 2!
This works for a case where the repeated chars is only two but above two returns an incorrect answer i will need the general case. If this is not clear then see this stack overflow post second solution. Unfortunately none of the solutions i have found so far is a dp solution. I can't even get a good close form  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32282607/permutations-excluding-repeated-characters?lq=1

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  You'll get a lot more help, and fewer votes to close, if you show that you have made a real effort to solve the problem yourself.  What are your thoughts?  What have you tried?  How far did you get?  Where are you stuck?  This question is likely to be closed if you don't add more context.  Please respond by **editing the question body.**  Many people browsing questions will vote to close without reading the comments.   Also, your question reads like you are givings an assignment, rather than requesting help, which may offend some readers.

Answer (score 1):

A "closed-form" answer can be obtained using the [inclusion-exclusion principle](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle#Statement). Suppose there are $d$ numbers occurring twice; w.l.o.g. we can assume that these numbers are $1,\ldots,d$. For $1\leqslant j\leqslant d$, let $A_j$ be the set of the permutations with consecutive occurrences of $j$. Then the answer is the size of $\bigcap_{j=1}^{d}\overline{A_j}$, which we compute using IEP: for $0\leqslant k\leqslant d$, the size of the intersection of any $k$ of the sets $A_j$ is equal to $(n-k)!/2^{d-k}$, hence the answer is $$\sum_{k=0}^{d}(-1)^k\binom{d}{k}\frac{(n-k)!}{2^{d-k}}.$$

Comment: Thanks let me see how i can implement this closed form.

Comment: this gives all the permutations, how do i adjust the formula for unique permutations

Comment: What do you mean by "all" and "unique"? (An example would help.)

Comment: like if you have 2 1 1 as a sequence then the permutations is 3! = 6 
{2,1,1} {2 1 1}{ 1 2 1} {1 2 1} {1 1 2} {1 1 2}
i mean unique when it is 3!/2! = 3
All is  the entire permutations with order

Comment: For this sequence, we have $n=3$, $d=1$, and my formula gives $3!/2^1-2!/2^0=1$, which is correct (as "1 2 1" is the only good permutation in this case). What's the trouble?

Comment: Oh i see, i tried  1 1 2 2 3 3 n=6 and d =3 gives me 66.... not 30 i'm i doing it wrong

Comment: $$\frac{6!}{2^3}-3\cdot\frac{5!}{2^2}+3\cdot\frac{4!}{2^1}-\frac{3!}{2^0}=90-3\cdot 30+3\cdot 12-6=30.$$

Comment: Excellent i was making an error. get it now Thanks so much